# ODBC Suddenly 100x Slower

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, teradata-sql-assistant

Running a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE` from a small table (10k rows) takes 1 minute to run. It used to take 1 second and still takes 1 second on my coworkers computers. Running queries on larger tables in reasonable time is now impossible.

I've tried querying from Teradata SQL Assistant and a Jupyter Notebook; both are extremely slow. I've tried querying various ODBC Data Sources, all are suddenly slow.

I've tried deleting and then adding back the Data Sources in my ODBC Administrator. I've compared my ODBC settings to those of coworkers and they're exactly the same.

Comment: Double-check that ODBC tracing did not get enabled somehow.

Comment: @GordThompson THANK YOU! Tracing was on for some reason. Turning it off did the trick.